# AutoHotkey read lastline

Tags: autohotkey

i am trying to make a Script that runs a clicking macro that continues until the last line in the text file says something specific.

dont have a lot of experience

NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode, Event  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
SetMouseDelay, 22

p::

Loop,  {

`Send, ^{Click 758, 243}
Send, ^{Click 903, 545}

Send, ^{Click 758, 305}
Send, ^{Click 903, 545}

Send, ^{Click 793, 329}
Send, ^{Click 903, 545}

Send, ^{Click 758, 454}
Send, ^{Click 903, 545} 

Send, ^{Click 1036, 412}
Send, ^{Click 1711, 719}
Send, ^{Click 1028, 259}

Send, +{Click 903, 545}


Loop read, F:\Cooking\bread\Flour_amount.txt
{   
    Loop, parse, A_LoopReadLine,    
    last_line := A_LoopReadLine, 
    if InString, A_LoopReadLine, Too much Flour,

        Break

    Else

        continue
}`

}

Answer (score 0):

The code above will loop infinitely (clicking the mouse then read through the file). If you wish to click for each line of the file and end when the specific line is read then only have the file read loop and place the clicks inside of it.

```
p::

Loop read, F:\Cooking\bread\Flour_amount.txt 
{ 
   ; Do something for each line in the file


   if InString, A_LoopReadLine, Too much Flour, 
      Break 
}
```

Comment: But the thing is, its should only read the last line, because its a log file from a game, so its constantly getting new logs